# Create constexpr template function to sum any container in C++

Tags: c++

I need to create a constexpr template function to sum container, and pass the static assert. This is my code, but I have to questions.

1. I recived this error: assignment of read-only reference ‘res’.
2. Is the sum function written correctly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
constexpr auto Sum(const T& arr)
{
    using arrType = decltype(*arr.begin());
    arrType res = 0;
    for (auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++) {
        res += *it;
    }
    return res;
}
 
int main()
{
    constexpr array<int, 3> base{5, 2, 0};
    static_assert(Sum(base) == 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not all containers are constexpr constructible so this will not work in general. And thus your code will revert to runtime evaluation in those cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because since `arr` is const reference, `decltype(*arr.begin())` is `const int`. So your `res` is `const` and you can't assign to it in your loop.

To fix only that error, you should use [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), i.e:

```cpp
using arrType = std::decay_t<decltype(*arr.begin())>;
```

You don't specify what you mean by "container". If you mean the [standard library's definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) (which is supported by all STL containers), you can use `value_type` instead and also further simplify your code:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto Sum(const T& arr) {
    typename T::value_type result{};
    for (auto const& x : arr) {
        result += x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you have C++20, you can also use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto Sum(const T& arr)
{
    return std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
                           typename T::value_type{});
}
```

Comment: Note std::accumulate is only constexpr since C++20

Comment: Thx, good point, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `decltype(*arr.begin())`, which gives `const U&` if `U` represents the type of the elements of the container `arr`.

Applying `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_cv` makes it compile.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
constexpr auto Sum(const T& arr)
{
    using arrType = remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<decltype(*arr.begin())>>;
    arrType res = 0;
    for (auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++) {
        res += *it;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr array<int, 3> base{5, 2, 0};
    static_assert(Sum(base) == 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this can be simplified with `std::remove_cvref_t<...>` in C++20